# Prove that $ϕ_{X_1}(u) =e^{−|u|}$ is the characteristic function of $f_{X_{n}}(x) = \frac{1}{π(1+x^2)}$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I have a problem with this exercise:

Let $(X_{n})_{n ∈ \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed, real-valued random variables whose distribution function is absolutely continuous with density:
$f_{X_{n}}(x) = \frac{1}{π(1+x^2)}$.

I have to show that $ϕ_{X_1}(u) =e^{−|u|}, ∀u ∈ \mathbb{R}$ is the characteristic function of $f_{X_1}$

I know that a characteristic function is really the characteristic function of distribution fuction when it applies:

$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-itx}ϕ(t)dt$

So I have inserted what I have in the equation:

$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-itx}e^{-|t|}dt$

But now i don't know how to continue, can someone help me?

Comment: Would you prefer help with computing the cf from the PDF or the PDF from the cf? How much complex analysis do you know?

Comment: Split the integration into two parts: one for negative $t$, and one for positive $t$.

Comment: @KBS has advised on computing the PDF. To compute the cf, my hint is the residue theorem with a semicircular contour. (You'd want to do $t>0$ first, then use $\phi(-t)=\phi^\ast(t)$.)

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know how to come to the result